# Precalculus Vector Questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. An airplane is flying on a compass heading (bearing) at 340 degrees at 325 mph. A wind is blowing with the bearing 320 degrees at 40 mph.

Find the actual ground speed and direction of the plane

This is my work:
[image]

I know I went wrong someone, I just don't know where. Can someone tell me what I got wrong?

2.A force of 50 lbs acts on a object at an angle of 45 degrees. A second force of 74 lbs acts on the object at an angle of -30 degrees.

Find the direction and magnitude of the resultant force.

This is my work:
[image]

The work is correct, except the final step. I looked at the answer and it  was the negative angle (-1.226 degrees) I was wondering what the logic was behind this.

Thank you very much

Comment: Your questions lack questions. What were you asked to find?

Comment: sorry, the questions have been added

Comment: Wind does not blow in a bearing.  Planes do not fly with a bearing. A bearing is an angular measure from the plane to a point on the ground (a visual reference point or a radio beacon).  And wind directions are reported in the direction the wind is blowing from. i.e. the weather vane points into the wind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother converting compass orientations to standard orientations.  Just assume that the real world does things like the mathematicians do, even when they don't

$(325\cos 340^\circ, 325\sin 340^\circ) + (40\cos 320, 40\sin 320)$

It should really be minus the wind vector, but I am sure that the person who designed this question doesn't know the actual conventions.  But, in my previous statement I just said disregard what is done in the real world, so we will keep doing that.

$\text {ground speed} = \sqrt { (325\cos 340^\circ + 40\cos 320)^2 + (325\sin 340^\circ + 40\sin 320)^2}$

True course.

$\theta = \arctan \frac {325\sin 340^\circ + 40\sin 320}{325\sin 340^\circ + 40\sin 320}$

However the arctan convention is to quote figures in $(-180,180)$  and you will need to add $360^\circ$ to get a number in $(0,360]$

In these sorts of questions it is also possible for the calculation to be off by $180^\circ$  You will have to do a little analysis as to which quadrant you are in and which adjustment you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 you want $v_{groundspeed} = v_{airspeed} + v_{wind}$. You have ground and air speed backwards. It's not a well explained question and you have to think of "flying on a heading..." as "aiming"
For the second question you have found out all the sides of the triangle and want to know the angle. If you use cos, which is symmetric about zero, you won't know if the angle is + or -. Using sin, which is symmetric about 90 degrees also gives two solutions. Using them together narrows it down to a unique solution. But then you already know the y coordinat is negative, so know that the angle is negative.
In your case it is best not to use cos. cos is almost flat near zero degrees so small errors in knowing the cosine will lead to large errors in the angle. sin and tan have a slope of 1 near zero so errors in sin,tan give the same level of error in the angle. You will thus have more acvurate results using sin and tan.